# Nest can't resolve dependencies

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I ran into a problem with NestJS dependencies, I just started learning Nest and still don't quite understand how to build the structure correctly.

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ChatGateway (?). Please make sure that the argument ChatAuth at index [0] is available in the ChatGateway context.

My error in terminal
[image: My error in terminal]

chat.module.ts
`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ChatAuth } from './chat.middlewares';
import { ChatGateway } from './chat.gateway';
import { AuthHelper } from '../auth/auth.helper';
import { JwtStrategy } from '../auth/auth.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [ChatGateway, ChatAuth],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [AuthHelper, JwtStrategy],
})
export class ChatModule {}
```

`

chat.gateway.ts
`

```
import {
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  OnGatewayInit,
  WebSocketServer,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  MessageBody,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io';
import { ChatAuth } from './chat.middlewares';

@WebSocketGateway(7000)
export class ChatGateway
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;

  private chatAuthHelper: ChatAuth;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('ChatGateway');

  constructor(chatAuthHelper: ChatAuth) {
    this.chatAuthHelper = chatAuthHelper;
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: string): void {
    console.log(payload);
    this.server.emit('msgToClient', payload);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('events')
  handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: string): void {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    parsed.msg = parsed.msg + ' 3';
    this.server.emit('onMessage', {
      msg: 'New message',
      content: parsed.msg,
    });
  }
  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log('Init');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    if (client.handshake.headers.authorization) {
      const guard = this.chatAuthHelper.use(
        client.handshake.headers.authorization,
      );
    }
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

`

chat.middlewares.ts
`

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthHelper } from '../auth/auth.helper';

@Injectable()
export class ChatAuth implements NestMiddleware {
  private helper: AuthHelper;
  constructor(helper: AuthHelper) {
    this.helper = helper;
  }

  public async use(token): Promise<object> {
    const currentToken = token.split(' ')[1];
    const user = await this.helper.validate(currentToken);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    return user;
  }
}
```

`

app.module.ts
`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as path from 'path';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { getEnvPath } from './common/helper/env.helper';
import { TypeOrmConfigService } from './shared/typeorm/typeorm.service';
import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module';
import { ChatModule } from './api/chat/chat.module';

const getPathConfig: string = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'env');
const envFilePath: string = getEnvPath(getPathConfig);

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath, isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({ useClass: TypeOrmConfigService }),
    ApiModule,
    ChatModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`

Swapped ChatAuth / ChatModule imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

come on, read the docs :D

- `ChatAuth` is not a module, then there's no reason it to be listed in the `imports` array.
- the page https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways shows that the gateway should be in the `providers` array. Again, `ChatGateway` is not a module, then why did you put that into `imports` array? the docs are pretty clear on what is the role of each option of `@Module({})`.